# Crystal reports suppression formula with multiple OR operators not working

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, crystal-reports-xi, suppress

I am trying to add a very simple suppression formula to my Crystal Report (XI) field but it is not working as expected.

I would like a text box to be visible if certain conditions are met, otherwise suppress. With the suppress box ticked my current formula is below:

```
{table1.field1} = "V1" or
{table1.field2} <> "V2" or
PageNumber > 1
```

If any combination of 1, 2 or all 3 of the conditions are met then display the text (neither `field1` nor `field2` ever return `null`).

However Crystal Reports is only evaluating the first line of the formula; if `field1 = V2` then the field does not show.

Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its a bit confusing but try below way...

if you are trying to meet all 3 conditions then you need to write that first because if any of the one condition is met first then control will never reach to `statisying all 3 conditions` and after that your regular conditions to satisy each one.

so your formula would be:

```
If
({table1.field1} = "V1" and
{table1.field2} <> "V2" and
PageNumber > 1)
then false        //don't Supress when all are met
else if {table1.field1} = "V1"
Then false        //field1 is met so don't supress
else if {table1.field2} <> "V2"
then false        //field2 is met don't supress
else if PageNumber > 1
then false       //3rd condition is met don't supress
else true        //Supress anything as all conditions were failed
```

Comment: The first 5 lines of your formula don't actually add anything to the logic... You can remove them and still have the same result.

Comment: Though it seems a lot of code to achieve something very simple - the use of an IF statement to cover all the possible scenarios worked - many thanks.

Comment: @Ryan i think you need to check your logic.

Comment: @Siva How so? You have three statements and if any of them are true then you return false. Then why bother checking to see if they're all true (first 5 lines of your formula) if that situation will already be handled by the rest of your formula?

Comment: @Ryan actually as per the requirement of the User there can be possibility of getting all conditions or getting any of the one condition.. In this case if getting all condition true is not handled first then control will never reach this step as at any point one or other condition will be true... so that should be handled first and rest after that... hope this is clear... or let me know if I need to make it more clear.

Comment: @Siva It is perfectly clear. What I'm saying is that whether all 3 conditions are true or whether only one of them is true does NOT affect the outcome; it'll still evaluate to `false` either way, so the first 5 lines are redundant. If you don't understand or believe me, I suggest you draw a truth table for these 3 statements.

Answer (score 5):

Suppression formulas work by suppressing the object when it evaluates to `true` and not the other way around. In other words, you need to negate your entire formula.

```
not(
    {table1.field1} = "V1" or
    {table1.field2} <> "V2" or
    PageNumber > 1
   )
```

becomes, via De Morgan's Law

```
not({table1.field1} = "V1") and
not({table1.field2} <> "V2") and
not(PageNumber > 1)
```

which can then be simplified to:

```
{table1.field1}<>"V1" and
{table1.field2="V2" and
PageNumber = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this If you just want to supress at the filed level-keep it at filed level; if you wanna supress the whole section- put this in section level.

IF
({table1.field1} = "V1" OR {table1.field2} <> "V2" OR PageNumber > 1)
THEN
FALSE
ELSE TRUE